# How do I implement register pages in Sleigh?

Tags: ghidra

I'm working on creating a processor definition for the  Motorola / NXP HC11 using the Sleigh language for Ghidra. A [definition for the HC12 already exists](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/tree/master/Ghidra/Processors/HCS12), so I'm working off of that.

The HC12 organizes its instructions into two pages: Page 1 with no prefix, and Page 2 with a prefix of 0x18:

[image: HC12 Register Map]

The HC11, on the other hand, has two more pages of registers:

[image: HC11 Register Map]

The HC12 processor definition uses a context variable and a recursive constructor to determine if an instruction resides on page 2:

```
define context contextreg
    Prefix18       = (0,0)    # 1 if 0x18 is the first byte
    PrefixHCS12X   = (0,0)    # 1 if first byte is 0x18 so that HCS12X to use GPAGE for memory access
    UseGPAGE       = (1,1)    # 1 if should use GPAGE concatenated to lower 16-bit EA
    XGATE          = (2,2)    # 1 if in xgate instruction decode mode
;
```

-

```
:^instruction  is XGATE=0 & op8=0x18; instruction  [ Prefix18=1; ] {}
```

-

```
:ABA                     is XGATE=0 & (Prefix18=1 & op8=0x06)
{
    result:1 = A + B;
    addition_flags1(A, B, result);
    A = result;
}
```

Another user, [also defining an HC11 processor](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/issues/1669), just used 16-bit instructions instead:

```
define token withprebyte(16)
  pre   = (0,16);
define token byte(8)
  op8   = (0,7);

OFF: op8    is op8 { export *[const]:2 op8; }
IMM8: op8 is op8 { export *[const]:1 op8; }

:bsetY OFF,IMM8 is pre=0x181C; OFF; IMM8
{
  local temp = *:1 (Y+OFF);
  temp = temp | (IMM8);
  *:1 (Y+OFF) = temp;
}
:bclrY OFF,IMM8 is pre=0x181D; OFF; IMM8
{
  local temp = *:1 (Y+OFF);
  temp = temp & (~IMM8);
  *:1 (Y+OFF) = temp;
}
```

The approach used on the HC12 seems bizarre and complicated to me. I also don't see how it will work for more than one page. Is there a reason I shouldn't just use 16-bit tokens for those instructions which reside on other pages? Is using the context variable, as the HC12 implementation does, more elegant in some way that I'm not seeing?